# Sitecore cross-culture linking

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, cross-language

If I have an item in en-US and I want to link to the same item in zh-CN culture from the en-US version in the rich text editor, how can I accomplish that? Also, how will the context language/culture be affected?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `?sc_lang=cn` querystring parameter to change the language of the current page.
I'm not sure if cn is the language code for Chinese ;)

That is the easiest way, but you can also use the embedded language paths if you set up your LinkManager to use it. You then need to set the `urlOptions.LanguageEmbedding = LanguageEmbedding.Always` and when creating a link, you can use the `options.Language` set to the desired language. 
Your url wil then be like `http://www.yoursite.com/en/itemname` where `/en/` is the code of the selected language.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on his question since it is not clear to me, but the second part, adding in the query string parameter will cause his context language to be changed to zh-CN.